# update if file on page doesn't match

Tags: php, loops, file, if-statement, header

I have a file for messages and i want it so when u add a message a if statement with a when loop try's to match a file size with an file size that was made form the start of the webpage and if it doesn't match (new message sent added to bottom of file) it would refresh to show the call the messages including the new message, I've looked for ages and i cent find a single one that works ill provide my code below can u please explain the problem..i cant find a single result of the problem;

```
<php
     $file = filesize("messages.php");
    while(true){ 

  

  $fileup = filesize("messages.php");
  if ($file === $fileup){
    die;
  }else{
    header("location: ./");

 }
    }
```

Comment: First, `while (true)` will create an infinite loop. However, your `if`-statement will either stop the execution of the script (your die;) or redirect the request away (your header()). Since either or will happen on each iteration, the loop is pointless (it will never make another iteration since you either die or redirect). And honestly, I don't 100% understand what you're trying to do. Who adds a message when/where? Could you give us a bit better explanation? Take it step by step.

Comment: im trying to create a messaging site  and i when some1 adds a message it adds to the bottom of the file and i want it so when the site sees a difference in the file size it would refresh so others will have message  this if statement checks if the fie size have changed

Comment: If you want to do a chat, I would recommend reading up on sockets instead.

Comment: ok thank you i will

Comment: I still don't get how it's thought to work. If you create an infinite loop, when would you run this script? Where? By whom?